# Main condensation line drilled and left inside 4"x12" main structural support

Tags: structural, support, condensation, install

Latent defect found by new licensed HVAC technician after original installer of unit said call somebody else. Ten year Carrier warranty now out. Not servicing my area. I called a new company out since again secondary  drain line was running so main drain line clogged again. We have only had issues with main drain line clogging since purchase and installation of new system.
New technician took me under the house and showed me where he found the main condensation line. Unit is in attic. Unit was purchased for new addition adding into our home. From the attic to out it was found drilled into and left inside main structural support of addition under house behind insulation and chicken wire. So Everytime this company who installed came out under warranty for clog issues they knew this install never met international property codes for installation.
Second AC company only discovered after asking if he could remove a section of underpinning of chicken wire and insulation where he thought it should be exiting under pier and beam.
By removing this material we were able to see they left main drain line inside structural support to spend the next ten years rotting out support
I'm in Texas. This is a latent finding and clearly not meeting international property code or manufacturer  installation requirements.
I want it fixed. Do I have a good case to take to small claims in TX. At $10,000 under for small claims that is about half what I need to repair.
Insurance company wrote telling me this was Contractor error and fault. To follow up with them once repaired. Licensed engineer wrote up findings Contractor error and support needs to be replaced. I've spent a thousand dollars so far getting documentation of this failure.
Any opinion às to how you would handle this issue? TY

Comment: Figuring out what was wrong is DIY. Figuring out how to fix it can be DIY. Figuring out how to sue to get it paid for? That's [Legal](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is more of a rant and a legal question than a home improvement question. Unclear if it's suitable/on topic for law.se - probably not in its present form, anyway.

Comment: I'd have spent $10 drilling and pushing the condensate line out somewhere other than inside the structural pier and called it a day.  I'd likely also write a bad review for the original company.  Typically the only person who wins in legal cases are the lawyers.